# Why TSC shows the errors on dependency module typings

Tags: typescript

I'm using some dependency for my app say module `fuse-box`

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/*", 
  ]
}
```

one of files in my codebase:

```
import { FuseBox } from 'fuse-box'

FuseBox.init({
  homeDir: '.',
  outFile: './built/out.js'
}).bundle('>app.ts')
```

TSC compiler gives me the error:

```
../node_modules/fuse-box/dist/typings/c
ore/WorkflowContext.d.ts(137,9): error TS7020: Call signature, which lacks retu
rn-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.
```

It is because of my `noImplicitAny": true` settings.
I just wonder why the hell it analyzes the stuff that out of my codebase and prints the error. Are such errors safe for dev process and compilation?

Comment: When I've dealt with this in the past it was an improperly written npm package that exposed .ts files as exports rather than using the package.json's typings entry. Those issues shouldn't be exposed here typically

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The compiler needs to go through the modules typing to give the proper type checking for you.

If you want to turn it off, you can do this in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

This requires TypeScript 2.0

UPDATE:
As usage of TypeScript increase and the use cases expended,
we start seeing issues even with `skipLibCheck` is set to true.

One of the issues is that it does not skip check in `node_modules` if the package includes `.ts` files.

The [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41883) is marked as `working as intended`.

Furthermore, you will hit with compilation error if the TypeScript version used by the package are different then what you are using,
and there are breaking changes between them.

Comment: This is an easy fix to the notorious "lodash/index.d.ts(13154,53): error TS2344: Type 'T'" error that so many projects are getting as a result of using dependencies that have lodash as one of *their* dependencies.  Thanks OP.

Comment: I have `skipLibCheck` set to `true`, but I still get errors in `node_modules`.

Comment: I have Typescript 3.8.3 and `--skipLibCkeck` does not prevent the compiler to go through the node_modules folder. Some *.d.ts files in the node-redis package are failing the build of the project. The documentation is not clear about this. I find it hard to believe that everyone has this problem, so there must be a way to achieve this. Any directions would be super appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

### It can't be done via tsc config

`skipLibCheck` doesn't apply when `require('foo')`. As of tsc v5, there's no configuration to fix this.

### Getting 0 exit status when *your* code passes

```bash
! npx -p typescript@5.x -- tsc -p ./jsconfig.json |
    grep '\.js(\d\+,\d\+): error' |
    grep -v '\<node_modules/'
```

1. runs `tsc`
2. selects only output in the format of `*.js(<l>,<c>): error: <message>`
3. exits zero unless something NOT starting with `node_modules/` is found
4. the `!` at the beginning inverts the exit code 
   (now 0 for empty string, 1 for non-empty string)

### npm run scripts

Note that it needs a few extra escapes `\\` when placed in a JSON string:

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "! npx -p typescript@5.x -- tsc -p ./jsconfig.json | grep '\\.js(\\d\\+,\\d\\+): error' | grep -v '\\<node_modules/'"
  }
}
```

## Caveats

I don't believe this works in Windows PowerShell.

This could be overcome by writing a node script that ran `child_process.spawn` and examined `stdout` instead of using `grep`.